# Java Scanner input into int and string arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

If someone would be kind enough to give me a hand with this program it would be appreciated, it accepts multiple students names and grades using a Scanner and then puts them into 2 arrays, Students and Scores.  Then it will print out like the following...

Max. Grade = 98 (Lauren)

Min. Grade = 50 (Joe)

Avg. Grade = 83.9

```
/* Chris Brocato
 *  10-27-15
 * This program will read the students names and scores using a Scanner and use two arrays to 
 * show the grade and name of the highest and lowest scoring student as well as the average grade.*/

import java.util.*;

public class StudentCenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of students: ");
        int students = console.nextInt();
        String[] name = new String[students];
        int[] scores = new int[students];

        int min = 0; int max = 0; int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter student's name: ");
            name[i] = console.next();
            System.out.print("Now enter their score: ");
            scores[i] = console.nextInt();
            if (i == 0) {
                min = students;
                max = students;
            }else {
                if (students < min) min = students;
                if (students > max) max = students;
            }sum += students;
        }
        System.out.println("Min. Grade = " + min + name );
        System.out.println("Max. Grade = " + max + name);
        System.out.println("Average Grade = " + sum);
        double avg = (double) sum / (double) students;
        System.out.println("Avg = " + avg);
        console.close();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: That's not a question. What problem specifically are you having?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not getting the correct output, both the min and max are giving out the same number, i presume it is just taking the last number entered but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `min`,`max`, and `sum` to the value of `students`, which is the number of students—not their scores. You should probably be setting them to `scores[i]`.

```
if (i == 0) {
    min = scores[i];
    max = scores[i];
}else {
    if (students < min) min = scores[i];
    if (students > max) max = scores[i];
}
sum += scores[i];
```

I would also store the **indices** for minimum and maximum scores, so that you can reference their names later.

```
 min = scores[i];
 minIndex = i;
 ...
 System.out.println("Min. Grade = " + min + name[minIndex] );
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, you solved my question, but when I did the min and maxIndex it put the first name typed in the output

Comment: You'll have to update the min/max index value wherever you update the min/max score values to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Min and Max values for constants.

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxValue = 0;
int minValue = 0;
String minName;
String maxName;

//then use them for comparison in the loop

if(scores[i] < min)
{
 minValue = scores[i];
 minName = name[i];
}

if(scores[i] > max)
{
 maxValue = scores[i];
 maxName = name[i];
}
```

That will store your max/min values with the associated name.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing min and max with incorrect values. students is the number of students you have not the grades. Also when printing tha names you are printing the whole array and not just a specific value. So my advice is that you create two variables like this:

`int minInd = 0;`
`int maxInd = 0;`

then change your if like this:

`if (i == 0) {
                min = scores[i];
                max = scores[i];
            } else {
                if (scores[i] < min) {
                    min = scores[i];
                    minInd = i;
                }
                if (scores[i] > max) {
                    max = scores[i];
                    maxInd = i;
                }
            }
  sum += scores[i];`

And print the result like this:

`System.out.println("Min. Grade = " + min + " ("+ name[minInd]+")");
  System.out.println("Max. Grade = " + max + " ("+name[maxInd]+")");`